# how to round/format Digit after decimal , if decimal values contain E as one item

Tags: java, decimal

I am having a double value -
`double d = 1.67303521E8;`
Whatever I used to format it , I couldn't get the actual solution.

I tried:

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.000");
```

and

```
public static double round(double value, int places) {
    if (places < 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException();

    long factor = (long) Math.pow(10, places);
    value = value * factor;
    long tmp = Math.round(value);
    return (double) tmp / factor;
}
```

but always the output is 1.67303521E8.
S0 finally I used

```
str.substring( 0,5 )
```

I want to know what is the actual solution to sort out this problem

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This way it should be formatted the way you want:

```
//This is just an object that can format numeric values into strings...
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.000");

//computation
long factor = (long) Math.pow(10, places);
value = value * factor;
long tmp = Math.round(value);
double result = (double) tmp / factor;

//formatting to string of specified format
String formattedValue = df.format(result);

//optional...
System.out.println(formattedValue);
```

Your mistake could be - which is a common one - is that you assumed that by doing something, you can magically alter the **format** of how the double value is **stored** in memory. This is not true. Doubles, dates, etc are always stored in native structures, you have to **format** them to be presentable to humans in the proper specified format.

**However**, you have one *blazing* mistake in the substring() approach: the `E` format - also dubbed as scientific notation - specifies an *exponential* after the E, which specifies which exponent of 10 the value must be multiplied by... This **important information is lost** in your implementation...

```
1.67303521E8
```

is actually

```
167303521
```

And not

```
1.673
```

Answer (score 1):

try again

```
System.out.println(new DecimalFormat("#.000").format(1.67303521E8));
```

output

167303521.000